# Как "вытащить" описание(caption) из фото aiogram python?

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно узнать описание из message.photo[0]

Answer (score 1):

Описание фото называется caption
Для получения описания из отправленного фото пользователем используйте

```
message.caption
```

Answer (score 1):

Описание называется `text.message`

Его можно присвоить к переменной, допустим `text2 = text.message`

Чтобы это описание вложить в отправляемое сообщение уже используется `caption`

Например `caption = text2`